# replace-regexp-in-string (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)

Tags: error

This used to work, but I somehow updated something, so now it doesn't run

```
; by Xah - http://xahlee.org/emacs/emacs_lookup_ref.html
#+begin_src elisp
(defun w3m-lookup-definiton-at-point ()
  "Look up the current word's definition in a browser.
If a region is active (a phrase), lookup that phrase."
 (interactive)
 (let (myword myurl)
   (setq myword
         (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
             (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))
           (thing-at-point 'symbol)))

  (setq myword (replace-regexp-in-string " " "%20" myword))
  (setq myurl (concat "https://www.google.com/search?q=" myword))
  ;;(browse-url myurl)
  (w3m-browse-url myurl)
   ))

(define-key my-mode-map (kbd "C-M-w l") 'w3m-lookup-definiton-at-point)
#+end_src
```

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)
  replace-regexp-in-string(" " "%20" nil)
  (setq myword (replace-regexp-in-string " " "%20" myword))
  (let (myword myurl) (setq myword (copy-whole-line)) (setq myword (replace-regexp-in-string " " "%20" myword)) (setq myurl (concat "https://www.google.com/search?q=" myword)) (w3m-browse-url myurl))
  w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item()
  funcall-interactively(w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item)
  call-interactively(w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item nil nil)
  command-execute(w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item)
```

Seems I pasted the wrong code;). Here's the correct one:

```
(defun w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item ()
  "Look up the current word's definition in a browser.
If a region is active (a phrase), lookup that phrase."
 (interactive)
 (let (myword myurl)
   (setq myword (copy-whole-line))
  (setq myword (replace-regexp-in-string " " "%20" myword))
  (setq myurl (concat "https://www.google.com/search?q=" myword))
  ;;(browse-url myurl)
  (w3m-browse-url myurl)
   ))
```

ok, so it's copy-whole-line that needs to return the copied line;)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The backtrace refers to the function `w3m-loopup-first-clipboard-item` but the code you show is about an unrelated function.

Comment: `(thing-at-point 'symbol)` can return `nil`. When it does, it is passed to `replace-regexp-in-string` which throws the error.

Comment: The problem is that `(copy-whole-line)` returns nil. The job of `copy-whole-line` is not to return the line but to put it on the `kill-ring`. That's at least what the backtrace says.

I didn't analyze `w3m-lookup-definiton-at-point` since that is not part of the backtrace.